# In a wxGrid, how do I allow selection of only one cell?

Tags: wxgrid

I'm using a wxGrid and would like the user to only be able to select one cell, not a block of cells.  (Or possibly multiple cells in the same column, but not necessarily the entire column.)  The only idea I've had that had a chance of working was to put ClearSelection() in the EVT_GRID_CMD_RANGE_SELECT but (not too surprisingly) this caused a stack overflow.